# how to set length of box in golang using andlabs ui?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, user-interface, go

I am making a graphics page using andlabs ui. I want to increase length of seearch box. How can we increase it? How can we increase box length and set box height and width?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/andlabs/ui"
)


func main() {
    err := ui.Main(func() {

        hbox := ui.NewHorizontalBox();      

        left_hbox := ui.NewHorizontalBox();
        hbox.Append(left_hbox, true)

        search_vbox := ui.NewVerticalBox()
        hbox.Append(search_vbox, true)

        search_hbox := ui.NewHorizontalBox()
        search_vbox.Append(search_hbox, true)

        search_input := ui.NewEntry();
        search_hbox.Append(search_input, true)

        search_button := ui.NewButton("      ");
        search_hbox.Append(search_button, false)

        right_hbox := ui.NewHorizontalBox();
        hbox.Append(right_hbox, true)

        upload_button := ui.NewButton("Upload")
        right_hbox.Append(upload_button, false)

        box := ui.NewVerticalBox();
        box.Append(hbox, false)

        window := ui.NewWindow("MyWindow", 800, 600, false)
        window.SetMargined(true)
        window.SetChild(box)
        window.OnClosing(func(*ui.Window) bool {
            ui.Quit()
            return true
        })
        window.Show()
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

How can we do so? Is there any function so that we can set box length?

Comment: This is an old post but I also encountered this problem and would like to know if there is any solution possible.